# Getting Unauthorized access to move data from blob to shareponit

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Azure I just tried to move data from azure blob to share point. But i am unable to create connection to storage account in logic apps. created blob storage and given access to logicapp. Need help

Why my question deleted?

encoded string. clientRequestId: xxxxxxxx More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is '*****'.

Comment: Could you please provide more details and error you got? and why your question deleted is error or are you asking something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue reproduced from my side and issue got resolved.

The issue your facing is with access key.

Created logic App as shown below and got the same error.
[image]

In my case the error occurred because of taking connection string instead of access key. So kindly check you are choosing key or connection string.
[image]

Make sure to copy **Key1 or Key 2** from **access key** .

[image]

Copy any of the keys from access key and paste it in **Azure Storage Account Access Key**.
After entering key in Azure Storage Account Access Key got the expected results as shown below.

[image]

Then click on create and  got the list blobs. In my case list blobs is my Azure blob storage action.
[image]